# XAML Strech TextBlock in Grid Colum

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone

[image]

Each list item must be

1. TextBlock 1 fill first row with 100% width;
2. TextBlock 2,3,4 must fill 33% each on separate row;

Why TextBlock 2,3,4 not strech?

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
             Text="{Binding Rest}" FontSize="28"/>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
             Text="{Binding Currency.Name}" FontSize="25"/>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
             Text="{Binding FullRest}" FontSize="22"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel></DataTemplate></ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

P.S.

How i can add 1...x rows in list view in design time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ListView.ItemContainerStyle

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code (with normal values, because I don't have the underlying data structure) works fine for me.

Different rows can have different widths however. That can be fixed by setting the Width of the StackPanel to the ActualWidth - margins of the listview.

You can find some info about how to add mock data, for usage in the designer, here: [How to get mock data into listview during design time and real data at run time in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378925/how-to-get-mock-data-into-listview-during-design-time-and-real-data-at-run-time)

Answer (score 1):

I used a ListBox to bind my data in similar way.

You will need to give stackpanel specific width

And you will have to set textwrapping property to 'no wrap'

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Width="480">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding main}" />
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding one}"/>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding two}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding thr}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

This Works perfectly for me!